# C++: 2D Dynamic Array allocation causing Visual Studio to crash

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm fairly new to dynamic arrays, especially mullti-dimensional dynamic arrays and I've scowered StackOverflow and C++ tutorial sites trying to find a fix to my problem, but I  can't seem to find any. Anyways I am trying to initialize a 2D dynamic array with values obtained from a text file and I'm experiencing some errors and problems. The numbers are meant to be placed inside the array to form a matrix. But every time I run my code it gives me an "Application.exe has stopped working error".

```
bool loadMatrix(const char *filename, int **matrix, int& rowCount, int& columnCount);

*matrix = new int[ rowCount * columnCount];

for( size_t currentRow=0; currentRow<rowCount; currentRow++) {
    for( size_t currentColumn=0; currentColumn<columnCount; currentColumn++){

        //This takes the value from the vector lines<> to be stored in the matrix
        int value = stoi(lines[currentRow][currentColumn], 0, 10);

        *matrix[currentRow * columnCount + currentColumn] = value;
    }
}
```

it is 100% something to do with the last line in the code above, as all the rest of the code had been given in the assignment skeleton. I have edited and changed the code in every way to try and fix the error. One attempt fixed it, but caused another bug with all elements of the array being overwritten by the last element, as seen below:

```
matrix[currentRow * columnCount + currentColumn] = &value;
```

But as you can see, this causes another problem, as now all the values in the matrix are overwritten by the last. As well, the array needs to be updated such that what values are added are accessible outside this function, and the above code won't allow the updated matrix to accessed outside of this function. Below is the output error of the above line of code:

1, 2, 3
 4, 5, 6

results as

6, 6, 6
6, 6, 6

I'm not too sure why the first attempt causes this error, but I understand the second attempt is due to some pointer to memory error.

Any ideas on how I could fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have bits and pieces of code that can't be compiled. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry I maybe made it too minimal, I know the error is definitely due to the code above, but I will add any relevant pieces of code now

Comment: You are not initialising your matrix properly. A matrix can be regarded as an array of arrays, so initially you need to set up the main array, whose each element is going to hold a pointer to another array. I guess your first line inside the function is attempting to do this. However, it should be done the following way: `matrix = new int*[columnCount]`. Then you need to iteratate over all the elements of this array and make each element point to a new array: `for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {matrix[i] = new int[rowCount]}`. This creates a new matrix with `colCount` cols &`rowCount` rows

Comment: That line of code is actually given in the skeleton code, which we were asked to fill out, so my lecturer had already declared it this way, so I'm not sure if I should change it. That being said, this was also one of my problems with looking for answers, because everyone else declares it the way you suggest. But like I said this is the way that code was given to me

Comment: `*matrix[bla]` should be `(*matrix)[bla]`. To avoid this error, use pass-by-reference .

Comment: This fixed it , thank you, if you want to put that as an answer, I will select it